# MySql - unknown column ename in having clause

Tags: mysql, having

```
MariaDB [testingcampus]> select * from employee;

+-----+--------+-----------+--------+
| EID | Ename  | City      | salary |
+-----+--------+-----------+--------+
| 100 | smith  | Bangalore |  10000 |
| 101 | carl   | Bangalore |  12000 |
| 102 | Ram    | Chennai   |  12000 |
| 103 | pankaj | Hyderabad |   5000 |
| 104 | vikram | Pune      |   2000 |
+-----+--------+-----------+--------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

For the above table when I typed the below code I get an error

```
MariaDB [testingcampus]> Select eid from employee having ename= "Vikram";
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'ename' in 'having clause'
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you don´t have to use having (it is used only for aggregated functions), you must use **where** like this:

```
 Select eid 
 from employee 
 where ename= "Vikram";
```

Answer (score 0):

From http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-having.aspx:

> The  HAVING clause is used in the SELECT statement to specify filter conditions for a group of rows or aggregates.

You don't aggregate, so try a `WHERE` instead of `HAVING`.